# Image plot only showing after last loop iteration

Tags: matlab

I'm tracking moving objects by iterating over a sequence of images. At each iteration of the for loop (once for each image), I show the image, as well as the circles marking each of the tracked objects.

This works as expected when I run it on just one frame. However, when running the full for loop, I only get the image + circle figure output for the last iteration in the loop.

If I take out the viscircles, and just show the image, it refreshes on each iteration as expected. What do I need to change with the circles to have them appear with the image on each run of the loop?

The loop in question:

```
for i=1:200

% Get the current frame and normalize the RGB values
frame = normalize( imread( [dataset_path images(i).name] ) );
rgb = imcomplement(abs(imsubtract(background, frame)));

[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[15 45],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.9);
[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(rgb,[15 45],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Sensitivity',0.9);

imshow(rgb);
viscircles(centers,radii);
viscircles(centersBright, radiiBright,'EdgeColor','b');

end
```

Comment: Putting a `drawnow` after the `viscircles` should help... Or otherwise some short, fixed delay.

Comment: @hbaderts A simple `drawnow` did the trick, thank you. If you want to add it as an answer, I can mark it correct.

Comment: Just a thought: you could try looking at the `movie` function.